# Two PHP classes: Only variables should be passed by reference

Tags: php

I have parent and child PHP classes. I can't use a variable from parent class as bind-variable in mysqli statement (php take it as constant?). Help me please
Look

```
<?php
class cparent{
    public $var1;
    public function __construct(){
        $this->var1 = 1;
    }
}
class cchild extends cparent{
    private $mysqli;
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();  
    }
    public function getVar1(){
        return $this->var1;
    }
    public function some_mysqli_func(){
        if (!$stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO bla(var) VALUES (?)")){
                echo 'Error: ' . $this->mysqli->error;
                return false;
        }
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $this->var1);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
}
$child = new cchild();
echo $child->getVar1(); //ок
$child->some_mysqli_func(); // Only variables should be passed by reference php
?>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

Comment: `some_mysqli_func` is private function. you can not access it outer side of class

Comment: Sure, should be public. It's just am example, take a look what the function does.

Comment: If you don't share the actual code you won't get the answer you need more than likely!

Comment: Thomas, the visibility is works fine. The problem is in mysqli statement.

Comment: Try changing `$stmt->bind_param('i', $this->var1);` to `$var1=$this->var1; $stmt->bind_param('i', $var1);`

Comment: I think it's because you're using `bind_param()` instead of `bind_value()`; try that.

Comment: What is the ***exact and complete*** error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the culprit:

```
$stmt->bind_param('i', $this->var1);
```

The `bind_param()` method makes its assignment by reference, which can only be done with a variable. `$this->var1` is, technically, a property. You can use a temporary variable:

```
$var1 = $this->var1;
$stmt->bind_param('i', $var1);
```

You can avoid a lot of this trouble by just using [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php):

```
$statement->bindValue(':var', $this->var1);
```

This will bind *by copy*, rather than by reference, and should give you much more flexibility.

Comment: It should be perfectly possible to pass *properties* as well, see https://3v4l.org/KS8pG. I'd be surprised if mysqli was an exception here.

Comment: Interesting. I also discovered that, unlike `PDO`, there is no `bind_value()`; all binding is by reference.

Comment: It's okay with both of solutions, but in case of existing module with hundreds of functions we have strong refactoring, that's undesirable. Maybe there's a third way associated with editing child class reference? Overriding var1, for ex?